# How do I conditionally compile C code snippets to my Perl module?

Tags: perl, swig, xs

I have a module that will target several different operating systems
and configurations. Sometimes, some C code can make this module's task
a little easier, so I have some C functions that I would like to bind
the code. I don't **have** to bind the C functions -- I can't guarantee
that the end-user even has a C compiler, for instance, and it's generally
not a problem to failover gracefully to a pure Perl way of accomplishing
the same thing -- but it would be nice if I could call the C functions
from the Perl script.

Still with me? Here's another tricky part. Just about all of the C code
is system specific -- a function written for Windows won't compile on
Linux and vice-versa, and the function that does a similar thing on
Solaris will look totally different.

```
#include <some/Windows/headerfile.h>
int foo_for_Windows_c(int a,double b)
{
  do_windows_stuff();
  return 42;
}
```

---

```
#include <path/to/linux/headerfile.h>
int foo_for_linux_c(int a,double b)
{
  do_linux_stuff(7);
  return 42;
}
```

Furthermore, even for native code that targets the same system, it's
possible that only some of them can be compiled on any particular
configuration.

```
#include <some/headerfile/that/might/not/even/exist.h>
int bar_for_solaris_c(int a,double b)
{
  call_solaris_library_that_might_be_installed_here(11);
  return 19;
}
```

But ideally we could still use the C functions that would compile
with that configuration. So my questions are:

- how can I compile C functions conditionally (compile only the code that
  is appropriate for the current value of `$^O`)?
- how can I compile C functions individually (some functions might not
  compile, but we still want to use the ones that can)?
- can I do this at build-time (while the end-user is installing the
  module) or at run-time (with [`Inline::C`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Inline::C), for example)? Which 
  way is better?
- how would I tell which functions were successfully compiled and are 
  available for use from Perl?

All thoughts appreciated!

---

**Update:** Thanks to all who responded. So here's what I did:

I considered a scheme of run-time binding with `Inline::C` inside of
`eval` statements, but ultimately settled on subclassing `Module::Build`
and customizing the `ACTION_build` method:

```
my $builderclass = Module::Build->subclass(
 class => 'My::Custom::Builder',
 code => <<'__CUSTOM_BUILD_CODE__,',
 sub ACTION_build {
   use File::Copy;
   my $self = shift;

   ### STEP 1: Compile all .xs files, remove the ones that fail ###    
   if (! -f "./lib/xs/step1") {
     unlink <lib/xs/*>;
     foreach my $contrib_file (glob("contrib/*.xs")) {
       File::Copy::copy($contrib_file, "lib/xs/");
     }
     open my $failed_units_fh, '>', 'lib/xs/step1';
     local $@ = undef;
     do {
       my $r = eval { $self->ACTION_code() };
       if ($@ =~ /error building (\S+\.o) from/i
          || $@ =~ /error building dll file from '(\S+\.c)'/i) {
        my $bad_file = $1;
        $bad_file =~ s!\\!/!g;
        my $bad_xs = $bad_file;
        $bad_xs =~ s/.[oc]$/.xs/;

        print STDERR "ERROR COMPILING UNIT $bad_xs ... removing\n\n";
        unlink $bad_xs;
        print $failed_units_fh "$bad_xs\n";
      } elsif ($@) {
         print STDERR "Compile error not handled in $^O:   $@\n";
       }
     } while $@;
     print "Removed all uncompilable units from lib/xs/\n";
     close $failed_units_fh;
   }

   ### STEP 2: Combine valid .xs files into a single .xs file ###
   if (! -f "./lib/xs/step2") {
     open my $valid_units_fh, '>', "lib/xs/step2";
     my (@INCLUDE,%INCLUDE,$MODULE,@PREMOD,@POSTMOD);
     foreach my $xs (glob("lib/xs/*.xs")) {
       open my $xs_fh, '<', $xs;
       while (<$xs_fh>) {
         if (m/#include/) {
           next if $INCLUDE{$_}++;
           push @INCLUDE, $_;
         } elsif (/^MODULE/) {
           $MODULE = $_;
           push @POSTMOD, <$xs_fh>;
         } else {
           push @PREMOD, $_;
         }
       }
       close $xs_fh;
       print $valid_units_fh "$xs\n";
     }
     close $valid_units_fh;
     unlink <lib/xs/*>, <blib/arch/auto/xs/*/*>;
     unlink 'lib/My/Module.xs';
     open my $xs_fh, '>', 'lib/My/Module.xs' or croak $!;
     print $xs_fh @INCLUDE, @PREMOD, $MODULE, @POSTMOD;
     close $xs_fh;
     print "Assembled remaining XS files into lib/My/Module.xs\n";
   }

   ### STEP 3: Clean all .xs stuff and compile My/Module.xs ###
   unlink <lib/xs/*>;
   $self->ACTION_code();
   return $self->SUPER::ACTION_build(@_);
  }
}
```

The check on `$@` is probably pretty fragile. It works on the systems
I've tried (all using gcc), but it probably won't work as it's written
everywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ideally, use [`Module::Build`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Module-Build/). At configure time (`perl Build.PL`), detect the platform and header location (but also let the user specify command-line options to override detection), set the relevant `extra_compiler_flags` and `extra_linker_flags` in the constructor and then copy the relevant files from e.g. `contrib` to `lib` (where they will be automatically picked up by `ExtUtils::CBuilder`). Now the distribution is customised to the platform - the next steps (`./Build ; …`) will work as normal.

Comment: Intriguing ... I'm going to bite the `Module::Build` bullet and try this out. Should the files in `contrib/` be C or XS? XS would be another bullet to bite.

Answer (score 2):

In one of my modules I have the following piece of code:

```
my $C_support = Module::Build::ConfigData->feature("C_support")

my $builder = Module::Build->new(
    ...
    config_data => {
        C_support => $C_support
    }
);
$builder->xs_files({}) if not $C_support;
```

Then in the code I detect it by loading Module_name::ConfigData and calling the config method.

```
if (Module_name::ConfigData->config("C_support")) {
    XSLoader::load(__PACKAGE__, $VERSION);
}
if (not defined &somefunction) {
    #define it
}
```

For details, look at my [Build.PL](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/LEONT/Scalar-Induce-0.02/Build.PL) and [Module.pm](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/LEONT/Scalar-Induce-0.02/lib/Scalar/Induce.pm)

Answer (score 1):

I've used techniques like this:

```
sub slow_function {
    # slow fallback perl code if possible
}
BEGIN {
    eval {
        require Inline;

        if ($condition) {
            Inline->import(C => q {
                int slow_function (...) {
                    // c function to conditionally compile
                }
            })
        } else {
            Inline->import(C => q {
                int slow_function (...) {
                    // c function with something different
                }
            })
        }   
        1;
    } or print STDERR "Inline::C error: $@ perl fallback used instead\n";
}
```

Comment: This is similar to the approach I had in mind, but compiling at run-time (taking the hit the first time `slow_function` was used rather than the first time the script was called).

Comment: That certainly works too.  In my case I knew I was going to need the function ahead of time.  During development, one of the nice things about using Inline::C to do this is that simply changing the C code will trigger a recompile the next time its run, so there is no need to remember to rerun the Build script.